# Flutter: signing app issue, adding the previous keystore from v.1 of the app developed with Xamarin on key.properties throw exception

Tags: flutter, keystore, jks, android-app-signing

Tying to deploy a new version of a current app on Play Store.

I have the old **.keystore** file used in order to sign the previous app, and when I try to add the metadata on the key.properties file under the android folder I got the following exception

key.properties file content:

```
storePassword=xxx
keyPassword=xxx
keyAlias=key
storeFile=C:/Users/Nike/**key.keystore**
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageReleaseBundle'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: jarsigner.exefailed with exit code 1 :
  jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: key.  key must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

On the previous for other apps distribute I've generate a **key.jks** file and the distribution was done successfully.

But this app has already a first version on Play Store developed using Xamarin and now the new version developed using Flutter needs the previous certificate in order to be signed.

Answer (score 0):

The issues occurred because the **keyAlias=key** was not correct.

```
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin>keytool -v -list -keystore C:\Users\Nike\keyname.keystore
```

Under the java keytool location.
Was able to found the Alias name for the **keyname.keystore**.

```
storePassword=xxx
keyPassword=xxx
keyAlias=newAliasName
storeFile=C:/Users/Nike/**key.keystore**
```

`Flutter clean` and `flutter build appbundle` create the app bundles